# HDMI cable does not fit into GTX 680

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, desktop-computer

I'm trying to plug a 2nd monitor into my GTX 680's HDMI port and the cable just does not fit. There seem to be 2 metal tabs and the top of the inside of the port that restrict the cable from entering and no amount of jiggling made it possible to push it in... I'm nearly positive I'm not trying to get it to fit into the display port because my Mobo has a display port and it is labeled and I'm not plugging it into that one. What do I do/did anyone else have this problem and managed to fix it?

This is what the port looks like (and you can sort of see the two tabs at the top):
[image: HDMI port with tabs]

And here is the HDMI cable I'm trying to plug in:
[image: HDMI cable]

Comment: Any chance you could post a photo of the plug and port?

Comment: From [here](http://www.geforce.com/sites/default/files-world/styles/652_width/public/product_images/geforce-gtx-680/geforce-gtx-680-bracket-1000x580.png?itok=4XNcdlch) first or second connector on the bottom?

Comment: @Cornelius the right one (2nd). And I'll try to get a picture of it up!

Comment: @fixer1234 I added pictures!

Comment: Is what you're referring to what looks like metal guides on the sides of the top socket?  Are those hitting the body of the connector?

Comment: @fixer1234 No, what I'm pretty sure is preventing the cable from being plugged in are the two metal tabs at the top of the port. They stick out minimally, but they are the only plausible obstacle I can see...

Comment: Looking at the picture, the plug should fit inside the continuous metal band of the socket.  It looks like there are two dimples or tabs in the top of that band.  It also looks like the socket inside the band is not centered in the opening.  The alignment may be off.  If you can open it up and get behind the shell, you could look for a way to adjust the alignment a little.  I see @davidbaumann suggested that before I got this posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the case oft your PC.

Then loosen the screws of the graphics card a litte bit.

Hold the card, centering the HDMI Port. Tight the screws, and try again.

Comment: I did not end up having to adjust anything, but I did remove the GPU to get a better angle while testing and wiggling the cable up and down a bit while pushing made it finally work!